# React - how do I get a value/variable from server side to client side

Tags: reactjs, express, client-server, display, data-transfer

My client side have all the filename that are in my folders.

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var formidable = require('formidable');

var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

function test(){
        fs.readdir('./uploads/', function(err, files) {
                console.log(files); //here are the filename I wanted to get
                return files;
        });
}
```

**Dropuploadfile.js**

```
    render() {
    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
            <h1>Drop &amp; Upload Files</h1>
            <DropZoneBox url={this.props.url} onUploaded={this.appendThumbnail} />
            <Output files={this.state.files} />
            <br/>
            <h2>List of Uploaded File</h2>
            <div className="hh">
                <ul>
                  <li>Test</li> // how to display all the filename at here ????????
                    <li>Test</li>
                    <li>Test</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I need to display all the filename that i get at server.js and display at dropuploadfile.js, How ? Thanks

Comment: use axios library https://github.com/axios/axios